# Can I Check a Hand Truck on an Airplane/Amtrak?

Tags: usa, air-travel, trains, amtrak

So I have this hand truck that I would like to bring home that I brought out in a car, but I am flying back. I figured I can't carry it on, but can I check it? It's about 50 inches tall, 21 inches wide at its widest point, and from the edge of the lip to the back of the wheel is 17 inches.

Update:
Okay follow-up question, can one bring it on/check it on Amtrak?

[image]

I plan to fly with JetBlue or American Airlines.

Comment: What airline are you flying?

Comment: JetBlue or American

Comment: I think the question of whether it can be taken on Amtrak is separate. Please ask it as a new question rather than editing it into this on.

Answer (score 5):

The four largest US airlines have the same maximum size for checked luggage: the length plus width plus height of the item may not exceed 62 inches.  ([Southwest](https://www.southwest.com/html/customer-service/baggage/) [United](https://www.united.com/web/en-us/content/travel/baggage/checked-baggage.aspx?POS=US) [American](https://www.aa.com/i18n/travel-info/baggage/checked-baggage-policy.jsp) [Delta](https://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/baggage/before-your-trip/checked.html))  Your hand truck is well over that, so you will most likely **not** be allowed to check it.  Some airlines might allow it for an extra fee, but my guess is that the fee may exceed the value of the item.

You may be better off buying one at your destination.  Craigslist suggests that used hand trucks go for about $100-200.  You might be able to sell this one where you are, to recoup some of the cost.

For Amtrak, the maximum size (again length plus width plus height) is 75 inches: see [here](https://www.amtrak.com/onboard/baggage-policy/checked-baggage.html).  You are over that as well.

(Note: I found all of these very quickly by Googling for (airline name) + "baggage size".  You might try the same if you need to know the answer for  any other airlines or transportation companies.)

Comment: The [model shown](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Milwaukee-800-lb-Capacity-D-Handle-Hand-Truck-HD800P/100030159) in the picture is $63 at Home Depot USA. This isn't worth the oversize baggage charge the airline would impose.

Answer (score 4):

I had a musical instrument in its case that measured almost a 100 linear inches. Lufthansa took it but charged me excess baggage of about $200 (FRA -> JFK). YMMV, especially on domestic routes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a cargo service like [American Airlines cargo](https://www.aacargo.com/ship/aircraft-compatibility.html) if you really want to take it. Alternatively, airlines could take it as oversized luggage and charge a extra fee.

**Amtrak will take it as oversized baggage**.

The [baggage guidelines](https://www.amtrakvacations.com/trip-planning/baggage-guidelines/) state:

> - 2 free checked bags, up to 50 lbs and 75 linear inches (length + width + height)
> - Oversized baggage accepted for $20/bag (76-100 linear inches)